# Does SSLSocket.startHandshake include certificate verification and hostname verification for SSLSocket?

Tags: authentication, ssl, socket.io, jce, sslsocketfactory

From the security guide https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs, when an SSLSocket is used seperated from the HttpsUrlConnection, hostname verification is required manually by invoking the hostnameverifier.verify() method:

```
// Open SSLSocket directly to gmail.com
SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("gmail.com", 443);
HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
SSLSession s = socket.getSession();


// Verify that the certicate hostname is for mail.google.com
// This is due to lack of SNI support in the current SSLSocket.
if (!hv.verify("mail.google.com", s)) {
    throw new SSLHandshakeException("Expected mail.google.com, "
                                    "found " + s.getPeerPrincipal());
}

// At this point SSLSocket performed certificate verification and
// we have performed hostname verification, so it is safe to proceed.

// ... use socket ...
socket.close();
```

But I also see secure code examples says:

```
/*
 * This example demostrates how to use a SSLSocket as client to
 * send a HTTP request and get response from an HTTPS server.
 * It assumes that the client is not behind a firewall
 */

public class SSLSocketClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory factory =
                (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket socket =
                (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("www.verisign.com", 443);

            /*
             * send http request
             *
             * Before any application data is sent or received, the
             * SSL socket will do SSL handshaking first to set up
             * the security attributes.
             *
             * SSL handshaking can be initiated by either flushing data
             * down the pipe, or by starting the handshaking by hand.
             *
             * Handshaking is started manually in this example because
             * PrintWriter catches all IOExceptions (including
             * SSLExceptions), sets an internal error flag, and then
             * returns without rethrowing the exception.
             *
             * Unfortunately, this means any error messages are lost,
             * which caused lots of confusion for others using this
             * code.  The only way to tell there was an error is to call
             * PrintWriter.checkError().
             */
            socket.startHandshake();

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                                  new BufferedWriter(
                                  new OutputStreamWriter(
                                  socket.getOutputStream())));

            out.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
            out.println();
            out.flush();

            /*
             * Make sure there were no surprises
             */
            if (out.checkError())
                System.out.println(
                    "SSLSocketClient:  java.io.PrintWriter error");

            /* read response */
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                    socket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);

            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Whether it is secure? I didn't see any hostname verify method is called before the read/write behavior of this socket. Does the socket.startHandShake() includes it?

Comment: It includes certificate verification. Hostname verification isn't part of TLS, it is part of HTTPS, at least prior to SNI. Don't use `PrintWriter` over a network: use `BufferedWriter`. And the end of line in HTTP is defined as `\r\n`, not as whatever `println()` might do.

Comment: From the page you quote, there is: "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:374)" This seems to show that startHandshake does indeed check the hostname.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek No, it shows that it checks the certificate.

Comment: @user207421 "Hostname verification isn't part of TLS, it is part of HTTPS," That would be strange since you can use TLS for many other protocols that have the same need, like LDAP, IMAP, XMPP, etc. See RFC6125

Comment: @user207421 checking the certificate may also mean checking the hostname, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-6

Comment: @PatrickMevzek It may be strange but it is certainly true. And this is why`HostnameVerifier` is part of `HttpsURLConnection`, not `SSLSocket`. I don't see anything in your link that mentions verifying the hostname against the desired target IP address. And it is still only a 'proposed standard' after 8 years. And the meaning of 'trust anchor not found' is that a trusted signer of the peer certificate couldn't be found in the truststore. See the many duplicate questions here with that title..

Comment: @user207421 "verifying the hostname against the desired target IP address." this is completely out of scope for TLS (except if the certificate has an IP address in the SAN extension, but that is rare)

Comment: @user207421 Look at B1, B3, etc. in the link. Clearly shows that the hostname verification is something not just for HTTPS. I am speaking here irrespective of implementations of TLS stacks, just of features in TLS stacks as applications are layered on top of it. But we will probably remain at this disagreement.

Comment: @user207421 if startHandshakes doesn't include hostname verification, does it mean this code example is not secure? I am not sure because it is an Oracle official secure guide.